# How can I delete an old github account from a PC permanently

Tags: github

I was using my account in my home pc. But now I am working at office. In office PC there was an old account. Whenever I am adding/pushing a repository into my account, it is updating but old person picture is still there. Contribution overview is not updating. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZXQk.png)
What can I do Now?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lQhm.png)
This picture is showing here is old person account picture. It is automatically appearing without my picture

I am using windows 10 operating system. I have deleted github old account from manage windows credential. I have also run this command "git credential-manager uninstall"